# Why shift right operator in swift and java get diffrence result

Tags: java, swift

I am trying to convert my code from java to swift, but when execute shift right operator with Int type then get 2 diffrence results.

//java

```
int d = 25;
int x = d >> 1 + 1;
System.out.println(x); //output: 6
```

//swift (4)

```
 let d = 25
 let x = d >> 1 + 1
 print(x)  //output: 13
```

What is solution for swift code?

Comment: Operator precedence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is calculating

```
d >> (1+1)
```

which is 6.

Swift is calculating

```
(d >> 1) + 1
```

which is 13.

You can use parentheses to specify which calculation you want to do.

This is because of *operator precedence*:

- In Swift -
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator_declarations - `<<` comes before `+`.
- In Java - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html - `+` comes before `<<`

Answer (score 4):

Java and Swift have different relative precedence levels for `additive`(`+`/`-`) and `shift`(`<<`, `>>`) operators:

- [In Java precedence of `additive` is higher than `shift`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), so it's performed first: `d >> (1 + 1)`
- [In Swift precedence of `shift` is way higher than `additive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator_declarations) so it's: `(d >> 1) + 1`

Answer (score 2):

operator precedence.

in the first sample the result is for

```
int x = d >> (1 + 1);
```

while in the second it is for

```
int x = (d >> 1) + 1;
```